# How to use "not" in XPath?

Tags: dom, xpath, xpathquery

I want to write something of the sort:

```
//a[not contains(@id, 'xx')]
```

(meaning all the links who's 'id' attribute doesn't contain the string 'xx')

I can't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

`not()` is a function in XPath (as opposed to an operator), so

```
//a[not(contains(@id, 'xx'))]
```

Comment: is there a way to say grab all the <p> tags but not the <a> tag inside them? imagine something like <p>text text<a class="x">TEXT</a>text text</p> . i want all the text in p but not the TEXT in a. is that possible with XPath? This isn't exactly my case, it's a little more complicated than that but its more or less the same.

Comment: @Ali Does `ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE` of `./text()|./*[not(self::a)]//text()`, passing the paragraph in as the `contextNode`, solve your use-case? \([jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fkg14a26/)\) *(note this won't exclude cases of `p>* a`, where the link isn't top-level, but it could easily be modified to do so.)*

Answer (score 42):

you can use `not(expression)` function

or

```
expression != true()
```

Answer (score 19):

None of these answers worked for me for python. I solved by this

```
a[not(@id='XX')]
```

Also you can use or condition in your xpath by `|` operator. Such as

```
a[not(@id='XX')]|a[not(@class='YY')]
```

Sometimes we want element which has no class. So you can do like

```
a[not(@class)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `boolean function` like below:

```
//a[(contains(@id, 'xx'))=false]
```

Answer (score 0):

not() function combined with "and" operator worked in my case. I am using typescript.
For example,

```
contains(text(),'textIWantToBeMatched') and not(contains(text(),'subTextIDoNotWantToBeMatched'))
```