# How to negate xpath query?

Tags: dom, xpath, xpathquery

I would like to do a negative xpath query like this:

```
$xpath->query(//a[DoesNotContain(@class,'some_class')]);
```

I know about this

```
$xpath->query(//a[contains(@class,'some_class')]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use "not" in xpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550981/how-to-use-not-in-xpath)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$xpath->query(//a[not(contains(@class, 'some_class'))]);
```

Comment: //a[not[contains(@class,'some_class')]]