# Selecting all the text except the last node using XPath

Tags: html, xpath

Is there any XPath pattern that can choose all the html code except the last node?
For example , lets say i want all the paragraphs inside the body except the last one in [this HTML code](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/asian-stocks-subdued-holiday-thin-005039608.html):
I tried these patterns which returned a null value or error in the expression (I'm using the HAP Testbed v1.1.0.0 to test the patterns on the HTML code):

- `//body//p[last()] != true`
- `not(//body//p[last()])`
- `//body//not[p[last()]]`
- etc...

**Question:**

- Does `not()` function return a boolean value? - If not, how can I use it for my purpose?
- Is there any other way to get all the text except the last node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a path expression `exp` selecting a set of nodes you can use `(exp)[position() != last()]` to select all but the last node in the node set. So use `(//p)[position() != last()]`. If you don't use the parentheses as in `//p[position() != last()]` you would select `/descendant-or-self::node()/p[position() != last()]` which would select all `p` elements that are not the last `p` child in their respective parent. So in the case of

```
<root>
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
</root>
```

that path `(//p)[position() != last()]` selects the first three `p` elements while `//p[position() != last()]` would select the first and the third `p` elements.

Answer (score 0):

To get all `p` tags except the last one and select their text, you can use

```
//p[position()<last()]//text()
```

`not(...)` is indeed [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550981/how-do-you-use-not-in-xpath) used inside conditions that returns a boolean.