# Json.NET JsonPath syntax for “does not include”, or negative matching?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to filter books in my json that does not have "name" property.

I found it is supported in Java JsonPath

```
$..book[?(!@.name)]
```

But when I use it in C# ::

```
json.SelectTokens("$..book[?(!@.name)]")
```

I got ::

```
"Unexpected character while parsing path query: !"
```

Also tried ::

```
json.SelectTokens("$..book[?(@.name == null)]")
```

Which is parsed but 0 results returned.

Comment: It looks like an xpath query, here's how to use 'not' in query if it's xpath... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550981/how-to-use-not-in-xpath

Comment: @quaabaam thanks, checked it but pretty sure its JsonPath https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm

Comment: Could you post a sample JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ syntax to get tokens that do not contain a property.

I don't know your exact JSON so I have mocked a simple example. If you post your JSON I will update my answer to work with your specific JSON.

Test JSON:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
        'books': [
            {'book':{'name':'some book name 1', 'author':'bob smith'}},
            {'book':{'author':'mary smith'}}
            ]}");
```

How to get tokens without `name` property:

```
var result = o.SelectTokens("books[*].book").Where(t => t["name"] == null);

// result = {{  "author": "mary smith" }}
```